# Processing All Keyboard Inputs (Hooks)

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, virtual, keylogger

I'm making a program that records all the keyboard actions, and stores this information into a log file (Keylogger). I just can't seem to find a good way of doing this.

**What I have so far:** A LowLevelKeyboardProc, The Virtual Key Code + the Scan Code of the Key being pressed.

**What I would like:** Using these codes, I will process and write information about the keyboard action being done. For invisible keys I would like the format: **"[SHIFT], [ENTER], [ESC], etc.** And for visible keys I would simply like their Ascii value (both Upper Case, and Lower Case), including if they enter: **!@#$%,etc.**.

I have a few ideas, but I don't know how I could capture everything. I have the information, I just don't know how to process it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my post from here: [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107886/soundplayer-causing-memory-leaks/4840387#4840387)

I've got example code for how to install a low-level keyboard hook and how to process the keystrokes.

Comment: I'm not able to fully understand C#. Could you explain it in layman terms?: What you did with the values from the hookproc, etc.

Comment: @Logostic: don't feel bad, because that's assembly, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the hook working, all you need is a mapping from key codes to names for special keys. Just pre-populate an array of strings indexed by the key code:

```
const char *map[256];

map[VK_SHIFT] = "[SHIFT]";
map[VK_ENTER] = "[ENTER]";
...
```

Then in your hook function, check if the key is a printable character, if so, print it directly, otherwise lookup the name of the key and print that:

```
if (isprint(vkCode))
  yourFile << char(vkCode);
else
  yourFile << map[vkCode];
```

Comment: "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token" on line "map[VK_SHIFT] = "[SHIFT]";". I'm missing something aren't I?

Comment: @Logostic: Maybe the identifier `map` is conflicting with the `std::map` container. Try using a different name.

Comment: I changed the name, same problem.

Comment: @Logostic: It works fine for me. Where did you type in this code?

Comment: I used it globally, and I tried adding "public" but that didn't work either. I don't want to write it in my hookproc because wouldn't it cause them to be declared every time?

Comment: @Logostic: You can't initialize it at the global level. You can declare the map globally and initialize it once in `main` or elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's working by the way. I just want to know a few things. What's the benefit of using "const char *map[256];" over a standard map from the <map> class? Also, how would I be able to determine if a key exists in the "const char*" map?

Comment: @Logostic: Oh, this `map` was just a name to indicate that the array maps indices to key names. `std::map` is a generic container to map any key to any value. The array just contains `char *` pointers, and since they're global, they're `NULL` by default -- I'm not sure what you mean by "key exists".

Comment: Well I've reformulated my program, and when an invalid key is used in the map, the program closes. So I'm looking to make an if statement to determine if the key exists before entering the map. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Just check `if (map[i] != NULL)`

Comment: if (map[p->vkCode] == NULL) {
cout << "0";}else{cout << "1";}

I'm getting 1 from some keys that aren't in my map. And it doesn't print anything if I try to print the value.

Comment: @Logostic: You may have to zero out the array manually then -- loop through the array and set `map[i] = NULL` before you initialize your map.

Comment: If I were to put all of this into my hookproc, wouldn't declaring the array and all of its contents be a burden since it would happen every time I pressed a keyboard button? Do you have any suggestions regarding efficiency?

Comment: @Logostic: No, you need not put this into the hook procedure. You can make your map global and just initialize it once in your main function.